# flock fail in debian 7.11

Tags: shell, singleton, flock

I want my script run singleton,I refer to [flock](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/flock/),the script runs well except debian 7.11.

When I runs in docker debian 7.11,it gives the following error:
flock: ./single.sh Text file busy

I download the debian 9,it runs well,If this can not fixed,I have to try another way to make the script run singleton.

I wonder if there is a way to fix this.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# singleton exec
[ "${EDR_FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env EDR_FLOCKER="$0" flock -eno "$0" "$0" "$@" || :

echo "Helloworld"
sleep 20
```

Comment: With what arguments and what environment is the script supposed to be run?

Comment: @Armali I found the reason,the lock can not be the script self,should be another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why this fail,the argument of flock can not be the script self.
Modify the script as below everything works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
# singleton exec
[ "${EDR_FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env EDR_FLOCKER="$0" flock -eno "$0.lock" "$0" "$@" || :

echo "Helloworld"
sleep 20
```

Answer (score 0):

To override this bug you could recall write permissions from your script `chmod -w script.sh` or make it immutable if it should be runned from root `chattr +i script.sh`.